# C# PDF generation library for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, library, pdf, c#

I'm looking for a C# PDF generation library compatible with windows 8.1 apps. Is there any free for commercial use solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with using a commercial product, you should check out the [LEADTOOLS PDF SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf-pro). You can use the LEADTOOLS libraries to simply convert any previous documents that you have to a PDF format.

The easiest way of doing so would be to load your original document using our [RasterCodecs.Load()](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.rastercodecs~load.html) method then save using the [RasterCodecs.Save()](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.rastercodecs~save(rasterimage,string,rasterimageformat,int32).html) method and specifying the output as a PDF.

Just to show how simple this can be done here is a code snippet of the process:

```
 RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs();
 RasterImage image = codecs.Load(<PATH TO FILE LOCATION>);
 codecs.Save(image, <DESTINATION PATH>, RasterImageFormat.RasPdf, 0);
```

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to generate the PDF from C# on Windows 8.1 (and other platforms).

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.